# Making a java program run in the background of the computer

Tags: java, background

I've looked on some other posts about this, but didn't really understand much from it.

I've made a program that works like a server while capturing different pictures of the screen. Now, i'd like the program to just be active in the background - like the programs that appear under hidden icons. Programs that are not directly shown at the bottom taskbar.
Do i need to add some specific code inside my java program when i execute it to a jar file? Or do i need to create the project some other way?

[image]

[image]

I hope this was enough explanation 
- Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't need special things for it. Creating a executable jar is enough.

Comment: " like the programs that appear under hidden icons." What is it ???

Comment: And if you want to start it from the console but not associate it with one you can simply use `javaw` instead of `java`.

Comment: So you want the jar file to run in the background but you also want it to hidden so the user can only see it if they have set the folder options to "Show Hidden Files" ? @Ander Lassen

Comment: @BSD_ ah, no sorry - poor explanation. I want it to be shown when you open up the little icon that shows programs that run on the computer, but are not directly shown at the windows taskbar. See picture that i added.

Comment: ahhh the syatem Tray @AndersLassen

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something super simple that I got from [Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/systemtray.html). All I did was add an exit on click.

**Code**

```
public static void main (String [] args) {
    if (!SystemTray.isSupported()) {
        System.out.println("SystemTray is not supported");
        return;
    }
    Image image = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage("MY/PATH/TO_IMAGE");

    final PopupMenu popup = new PopupMenu();
    final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(image, "MY PROGRAM NAME", popup);
    final SystemTray tray = SystemTray.getSystemTray();

    MenuItem exitItem = new MenuItem("Exit");
    exitItem.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.exit(1);
        }
    });
    popup.add(exitItem);

    trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);

    try {
        tray.add(trayIcon);
    } catch (AWTException e) {
        System.out.println("TrayIcon could not be added.");
    }
}
```

Just get any image and add it to your resources or wherever you keep your images and make a path to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using the `java.awt.SystemTray` API in combination with Java Swing API.

Refer this documentation from Oracle:

[Oracle Java documentation for System Tray API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/SystemTray.html)

Answer (score 0):

`SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(trayIcon)` does the job.

Here an example of one of my application :

```
Image imageTrayIcon = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().createImage(YourClass.class.getResource("trayicon.png"));
    final TrayIcon trayIcon = new TrayIcon(imageTrayIcon, "title");

   // optional : a listener
    trayIcon.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter() {

        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {

        if (e.getClickCount() == 2 && !e.isConsumed()) {
            e.consume();
           // process  double click
           }
        }
    });
    // optional : adding a popup menu for the icon
    trayIcon.setPopupMenu(popup);

    // mandatory
    try {
        SystemTray.getSystemTray().add(trayIcon);
    }
    catch (AWTException e1) {
        // process the exception
    }
```